# How to add a ChannelInitializer to TcpServer in reactor netty

Tags: reactor-netty

I have a NettyServerCustomizer which next code:

```
@Override
    public HttpServer apply(final HttpServer httpServer) {
        return httpServer.tcpConfiguration(tcpServer -> tcpServer
            .bootstrap(serverBootstrap -> serverBootstrap
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(final SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        final ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                        p.addFirst(new MyCustomChannelInboundHandlerAdapter());
                    }
                })));
    }
```

But reactor-netty have deprecated method `bootstrap` since version 0.9.10 by this PR: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/pull/1175.

How can I obtain the same behavior with new API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was deprecated because in Reactor Netty 1.0.0 `Bootstrap` and `ServerBootstrap` are not used anymore. https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/releases/tag/v1.0.0
There is no replacement for this particular use case in 0.9.x. In 1.0.0 the replacement is `doOnChannelInit`
If your build restricts the usage of deprecated APIs, please open a feature request and we will try to back port the API from 1.0.0 version.